# One Bucket - Multiple Topics Amazon S3, SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, serverless-framework

I am trying to two SNS topics for a single bucket event. At present, I have my bucket configured in this manner:

```
TranscribedBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    NotificationConfiguration:
      TopicConfigurations:
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Topic:
            Ref: Transformer
          Filter:
            S3Key:
              Rules:
                - Name: prefix
                  Value: "transcribed-"
  BucketName: ${self:provider.transcribedBucket}
```

The topic `Transfomer` is being listened by two subscriber lambdas and they actually output in the same bucket under different folders (say, folder1/file1 by subscriberLambda1 and  folder2/file2 by subscriberLambda2). Once that is done, I have one more lambda which needs to actually consume an SNS event whenever the file gets landed in that folder.

Since `- Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*` cannot be duplicated, I can't actually create one more `Topic` for the same bucket. How can I go forward with this?

Comment: Are you sure you can't add two subscribers? `TopicConfigurations` is an array, you should be able to add another item.

Comment: Agreed. They would need different prefixes.

Comment: @Alex I cannot add the same `s3:ObjectCreated:*`. That will lead to a conflict -- `Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.`. I can only add other events.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein How to add two different prefixes? Even if I do that how can I hook them up to individual lambda functions?

Comment: Your `Name: prefix` section is saying "Anything with a Key starting with `transcribed-` should trigger this event. You could create a second TopicConfiguration as long as it has a different prefix (eg not `transcribed-`). The prefixes are normally the names of folders, but can include the filename (since a Key actually contains both).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
TranscribedBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    NotificationConfiguration:
      TopicConfigurations:
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Topic:
            Ref: Transformer
          Filter:
            S3Key:
              Rules:
                - Name: prefix
                  Value: "folder1/"
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Topic:
            Ref: Bumblebee
          Filter:
            S3Key:
              Rules:
                - Name: prefix
                  Value: "folder2/"
  BucketName: ${self:provider.transcribedBucket}
```